# GitHub PR Merge does not trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, github, yaml, devops

I have my repository on GitHub and my CI/CD pipelines on Azure DevOps. What I want to achieve is, that once a PR merges onto the master branch that the pipeline deploys. No PR creation should trigger the pipeline. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the trigger right.
My trigger looks like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
pr: none
```

When I push changes onto the master branch, the pipeline gets triggered. But if I do it via GitHub PR, nothing happens. I also tried it with release pipelines but I seem to have the same problem there. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. Something is completely off in my repository. No idea how I managed that, since I thought that should not even be possible.
Anyway, I tried the triggers with an empty repository and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest just use `trigger` for CI

```
trigger:
branches:
    include:
        - master
```

Omit the `pr` section.

This would then run your pipeline whenever you make a PR to master as well as once you complete the PR.

And now to prevent the pipeline from running whenever you make the PR and only once you complete the PR to master, use a condition on your build stage

```
- stage: 'Build'
  displayName: 'Build my application'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')
  jobs:
etc.....
```

Comment: I tried that but still have no result. The second run after the merge never happens. I have a feeling that something on GitHub is not right. When I just push something on the master branch then it triggers, but not after I merge the PR onto master

Comment: Did you just try the PR once? retry it a second time. Will pick up the yaml then. This currently works for me. I run only the build stage on PR creation. then run the build + deploy using conditionals once the PR is merged. But sometimes I notice the first PR doesn't pick up the updated yaml, but the rest do. see here : https://github.com/rimaz523/micolk-backend/blob/develop/azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: basically make sure the yaml in your master branch already has the updated trigger & conditional before you try out the PR scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing with Pull-Requests from Github.  In the end i just used the old school "triggers" section and it started working.

Just edit the pipeline and in the "..." drop down selected triggers and then go to the "Pull Request Validation" row and enable it.  Lastly pick the target branch.

Note: sometimes is can take a few minutes for DevOps to pick it up.

Comment: I don't seem to have to option to enable "Pull Request Validation" as it seems to be enabled by default. I made a screenshot to show the options I have: ![Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/lVR9CVx.png).

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that you have to enable "overide yaml triggers".  Then it will show the option to enable it.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but now the pipeline gets triggered with the creation of the PR and not when the PR gets merged into master

Comment: I use different files for pr tests and full merge, but you can enable "Continous Integration" in the same settings are to give you the merge on the merge too.

Comment: Me too, I have a file for CI and one for CD. The CI works like a charm, but CD still doesn't work as I want it to. I tried to enable "Continous Integration" but without any results